# Restrict Autorotate to Landscape for iOS 5 in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5, rotation

I am working on app and developing on Xcode 5. App is for iPad from iOS 5 to iOS 7 support. I restrict app to Landscape Left and Right, which is defined in plist and Project settings. 
Also defined by code 
in App delegate

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window  
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

In Classes

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

But what happened, It works fine on iOS 7 and iOS 6 but it always rotated to iOS 5 when device move portrait. I am stuck here how to restrict this only on Landscape. Kindly help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

U can lock the orientation change.

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
    {
       if (autoRotate) {
         return YES;
       } 
       else
       {
         return NO;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
     if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
         return YES;
     else
         return NO;
}
```

By using above code is device is not rotate with portrait orientation.

Comment: Thanks @iPatel, I implement this method which is not calling on rotation but call when controller load once.

Comment: DOn't you think so, this may be the issue of device. Because I did every thing and also it working fine on rest of devices? What your experience say, is this possible?